# Check file on csv file streaming with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, cloudera, hortonworks-sandbox

Im working with spark streaming and don't want to process the old files when the new streaming file come every 10 minutes:

```
val val1= spark  
.read //  
.option("header", "true")    
.option("schema", "true")    
.option("sep", ",")    
.csv(path_to_file).toDF().cache()  
val1.registerTempTable("test")
```

after creating the dataframe i do some transformation and process
the checkpoint can help me and how i used in my case

Comment: thats ok i doit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*****************the solution*******************

val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("test")
    .config("spark.local", "local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(path_checkpoint)
and after i call the checkpoint function on the dataframe
And i specified a trigger to execute the job

```
   .writeStream
    .format("csv") 
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec") 
    .option("checkpointLocation",CheckPoint)   
 .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("180 seconds")) 
    .option("Path",Path )  
    .option("header", true)  
    .outputMode("Append")
    .queryName("test")
    .start()
```